# How to use Symbols

Tags: android, json

I have to show details in below format, and my JSON looks like this:

```
{
        "clubs":[
        {
            "title" : "Bold Eyes Night Club",
            "description" : "(Heading 1)Why We Like It (PointNo.1)Cook up your own food in the fully equipped kitchens. (PointNo.2)Up the street's London Bridge. (PointNo.3)Famous food shopping market few steps away from the door. (Heading 2)Need to Know (PointNo.1)All rooms to fit two people. (PointNo.2)18+ to book a room."
        }
    ]
}
```

**How to Achieve this:**

[image]

I have parsed JSON data, now i just want to show description in such format as shown in  above screen-shot

My mean `new line`, `dots`, `plus` and other `symbols`

Comment: Do you have control over the json?

Comment: yes i can make changes in this json, but any how i have to achieve this @stealthjong

Comment: Not an answer but I suggest you re-think the JSON structure. Instead of embedding things like "(Heading 1)" and "(PointNo.1) in the text you should have JSON objects and / or arrays to differentiate them from the actual text.

Comment: @Squonk ok no problem, can you show me the way how my JSON should look like for that, so i will make changes in mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have control over JSON, try to reconstruct JSON like below

```
{
    "clubs": [
        {
            "title": "Bold Eyes Night Club",
            "description": [
                {
                    "Heading": "Why We Like It",
                    "Points": [
                        "Cook up your own food in the fully equipped kitchens.",
                        "Up the streets London Bridge.",
                        "Famous food shopping market few steps away from the door."
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Heading": "Need to Know",
                    "Points": [
                        "All rooms to fit two people.",
                        "18+ to book a room."
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

After Parsing, while setting to TextView.

```
mHeading.setText(data.getHeading()) // "Why We Like It",
mHeading.setTextSize(24);

String mPoints = ""; mPoint1 +  + 
for(int i = 0; i < data.getPoints().size(); i++)
{
    mPoints = "&emsp;&middot;" + data.getPoints().get(i) + "\n";
}
mPointsTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(mPoints));
```

Or you can add symbols from your server, so you can have more control.

```
{
    "clubs": [
        {
            "title": "Bold Eyes Night Club",
            "description": [
                {
                    "Heading": "Why We Like It",
                    "Points": "&emsp;&middot;Cook up your own food in the fully equipped kitchens.\n &emsp;&middot;Up the streets London Bridge.\n &emsp;&middot;Famous food shopping market few steps away from the door."
                },
                {
                    "Heading": "Need to Know",
                    "Points": "&emsp;&middot;All rooms to fit two people.\n&emsp;&middot;18+tobookaroom."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}


mHeading.setText(data.getHeading()) // "Why We Like It",
mHeading.setTextSize(24);

mPointsTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(mPoints));  //&emsp;&middot;Cook up yo...
```

Comment: but what about symbols ?

Comment: @Sun check updated answer, you can either append the symbols in your android or send those symbols in HTML format with your string in Server, I would prefer the second.

Comment: yeah i also prefer second solution my mean HTML Server, please show the way of doing this ?

Comment: @Sun just add the symbols in HTML format. Check now.

Comment: thank you so much :) boss +1 but one doubt this json format is different from your previous json, which i have to use and please delete that one which is not useful - i already accepted your answer and ticked as useful

Comment: @Sun StackOverflow is not just for you & me, if anyone comes here with the same question, they might also use the first one. :) for your requirement use the `SECOND` one, `adding symbols in SERVER`

Comment: @Sun : I'd personally be tempted to use an `ExpandableListView` instead of individual `TextViews`. That way if there are more categories (headings) and points it will scale accordingly.

Comment: @VenomVendor hye bro please look at my question, following your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545076/how-to-show-multiple-headings-and-points-in-single-activity

Answer (score 1):

You can make dots like this:

Within Layout:

```
<View android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        />
```

Within drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval"  >
            <solid android:color="#ffaabb"/>

        </shape>
        </item>>

</selector>
```

Output:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Android-fonts doesnt support all unicode symbols. So assign your view/control the `DejaVuSans.ttf` - Font. This font supports all symbols.

*Example:*

```
Typeface unicodeFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "DEJAVUSANS.TTF");
yourView.setTypeface(unicodeFont);
```

Hope this helps you

Greets!

Answer (score 0):

try assci code for this

```
textView.setText("\u2022 this is DOT"); 
textView.setText("\u00B7 this is MIDDLE DOT"); 
textView.setText("\u000A this is new line");
```