# How to show Multiple Headings and Points in Single Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, json

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260192/how-to-use-symbols) SO solution, and i have successfully `parsed JSON`, but don't know How to show both the `headings` and `points` in TextViews.

this is how my `JSON` looks:

```
{
    "technology": [
        {
            "title": "Android",
            "description": [
                {
                    "heading": "Manufactures",
                    "points": [
                        "Google",
                        "Samsung"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "heading": "Platforms",
                    "points": [
                        "Kitkat",
                        "ICS"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ] 
}
```

For an example, if i do `tap on Android`, then i `want to show` something like this:

```
Manufactures
[dot] Google
[dot] Samsung

Platforms
[dot] Kitkat
[dot] ICS
```

For `reference` see this image:

[image]

In place of `Why We Like It`, i want to show `Manufactures` and in place of `Need to Know`, i want to show `Platforms` (with their respective points) as shown in Image.

But `getting` something like `this`:

```
Platforms
[dot] ICS
```

For `reference` see this image:

[image]

So what is the reason? and where i have to make changes in my code ?

**DescriptionActivity.java:-**

```
 for(int s=0; s<arrayListDescription.size(); s++)
    {
        description = arrayListDescription.get(s);
        strHeading = "&nbsp;" + description.getHeading();
        Log.d("heading::", strHeading);
        arrayListPoints = description.getPoints();      

        for(int z=0; z<arrayListPoints.size(); z++)
        {
            String dot = getString(R.string.dot);
            strPoints = "";
            strPoints += "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + dot + "&nbsp;" + arrayListPoints.get(z) + "\n";
            Log.d("points::", strPoints);
        }
        textViewPoints.setText(Html.fromHtml(strPoints));
    }       

    textViewHeading.setText(Html.fromHtml(strHeading));
    textViewHeading.setTextSize(20);

}
```

**activity_description.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textHeading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPoints"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is what my `Log` says:

```
08-28 04:47:39.653: D/heading::(1902): Manufactures
08-28 04:47:39.653: D/points::(1902): &emsp;&middot;Google
08-28 04:47:39.671: D/points::(1902): &emsp;&middot;Samsung
08-28 04:47:39.761: D/heading::(1902): Platforms
08-28 04:47:39.761: D/points::(1902): &emsp;&middot;Kitkat
08-28 04:47:39.761: D/points::(1902): &emsp;&middot;ICS
```

By `using` **@Dreagen's** solution, `getting` something like `this`:

```
Platforms
null[dot]Google[dot]Samsung[dot]Kitkat[dot]ICS
```

For `reference` see this `image`:

[image]

I used this code:

```
for(int z=0; z<arrayListPoints.size(); z++)
{
    String dot = getString(R.string.dot);
    // strPoints += dot + arrayListPoints.get(z) + "\n";
    strPoints += "&emsp;&middot;" + arrayListPoints.get(z) + System.getProperty("line.separator");
    Log.d("points::", strPoints);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ArrayList<Model> mydata = new ArrayList<Model>();
            // set 1
            Model model = new Model();
            ArrayList<String> points = new ArrayList<String>();
            model.setHeading("Manufactures");
            points.add("Google");
            points.add("Samsung");
            model.setPoints(points);
            mydata.add(model);

            // set 2

            model = new Model();
            points = new ArrayList<String>();
            model.setHeading("Platforms");
            points.add("Kitkat");
            points.add("ICS");
            model.setPoints(points);
            mydata.add(model);

            // String str =
            // "<h4>An Unordered List:</h4><br/>&#8226; foo<br/>&#8226; bar<br/>&#8226; baz<br/>";

            TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
            String result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < mydata.size(); i++) {
                result += "<h4>" + mydata.get(i).getHeading() + "</h4>";
                ArrayList<String> appendPoints = new ArrayList<String>(mydata
                        .get(i).getPoints());
                for (int j = 0; j < appendPoints.size(); j++){
                    result += "&#8226; " + appendPoints.get(j) + "<br/>";}

            }

            Spanned spannedResult = Html.fromHtml(result);

            textview.setText(spannedResult);

        }

    }
```

**Model**

```
public class Model {

    private String heading;
    private ArrayList<String> points;

    public String getHeading() {
        return heading;
    }

    public void setHeading(String heading) {
        this.heading = heading;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(ArrayList<String> points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

}
```

**XML :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.nestedtext.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[COMPLETE SOURCE CODE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8txoxp8z126c9ht/NestedText.tar.gz?dl=0)

Comment: Hey i need your help and that's urgent ! please come soon @DIVA

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here

```
for(int z=0; z<arrayListPoints.size(); z++)
{
    strPoints = "&emsp;&middot;" + arrayListPoints.get(z) + "\n";        
    Log.d("points::", strPoints);
}
```

You are just overwriting `strPoints` each time you loop, which means that the at the end you only have the last point in there. The log shows both because you output to the log everytime you loop.

Change it to:

```
for(int z=0; z<arrayListPoints.size(); z++)
{
    strPoints += "&emsp;&middot;" + arrayListPoints.get(z) + System.getProperty("line.separator");
    Log.d("points::", strPoints);
}
```

note the `+=` instead of just `=` and the change of `\n` to use `System.getProperty("line.separator");`
Hope this helps

Comment: I deleted my answer. I totally misunderstood the question. This answer is correct.

Comment: Looks like you're just having an issue with the line break. I will update my answer with something that should fix it

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dreagen's answer, you should change new line symbols to `br` tags. <s>Other solution is using `pre` for preformatted text, though I'm not sure if Android supports that tag.</s>

Comment: Android, sadly, does not support `pre` tags. Source: http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html